# Twisting four CANBUS wires (High, Low, GND, PWR)

Tags: wire, can, twisted-pair

From what I understand, the High/Low CAN wires must be a twisted pair and it seems like a bad idea to create a 3-wire braid with the High/Low along with the GND wire, let alone with PWR.

Just to be sure, High/Low and GND/PWR wires should be twisted separately, correct? (That also means in the case of a cable rather than separate wires, wouldn't there also be an issue?)

Comment: It depends. Is that specific CAN bus port isolated or referenced to ground? Is that specific device powered by these GND and PWR wiires or does it receive power from somewhere else? Is there another path for the ground to that device in addition top the GND wire?

Comment: High/Low should be twisted pair. No need for power.

Comment: As far as I can tell or understand, it is supposed to connect to a tapping device which is to tap into existing CANBUS to read it. I have currently made a twisted pair with the High/Low, but was wondering if I should have made a 4 or 3 wire-braid instead.

Comment: If there is no noise on GND/PWR relative to CANH/L, it doesn't much matter; mind the impedance will be somewhat lower.  There may also be stub length effects depending on how GND/PWR are connected and the cable length.

Comment: If you worry about noise, the CAN wiring should be a shielded twisted pair. But this starts to sound a bit weird - what do you mean by twisted? Did you just twist some random wires yourself, or did you use a ready made cable with suitable impedance for CAN bus?

Comment: @Justme I have to make my a CAN wire that is supposed to be attached to an external PCAN module (which will be connected to a computer through a serial cable). The PCAN itself has High, Low, PWR, and GND for the CAN. I am wondering if I have to make two twisted-pair wires of High/Low and GND/PWR, or if I have to make a 4-wire braid with all 4 wires (High, Low, GND, and PWR).

Answer (score 1):

You should not braid data wires with power wires.

In fact, you should not braid the cables yourself, at least not the data lines, unless you know the end result will ends up with correct properties for CAN bus.

You should buy a cable that already has a twisted pair which is suitable for CAN bus. Sometimes the twisted pair also has a separate shielding.

CAN bus has 120 ohm differential impedance, so you can't just take random wires, twist them, and expect to have a 120 ohm differential impedance.